# How is vector addition is true?

Tags: vectors

The vector is given by:
$$\overrightarrow{AC}=\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}$$

I remember using pythagoras theorem which I used to find the length another side of a triangle as shown here.

How come it is different in the case of vector addition and true?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're asking how it can be that here we have

$$\vec{AC}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}$$

whereas the Pythagorean theorem tells us that

$$AC^2=AB^2+BC^2$$

The answer is that the two equations are talking about different things. The pythagorean theorem is talking about the *lengths* of the vectors, whereas the vector equation is talking about the vectors themselves.

Comment: Would it not be more intuitive to draw it as [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/33vw3412l34ir6m/Untitled.png)?

Comment: @cpx Your diagram is correct, but the one you posted in your question is also correct. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @cpx In your diagramm $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{BC}$ are parallel.

Answer (score 2):

$$\vec{AC}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}$$

This is the [Chasles' Relation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Chasles'_Relation). Pythagorus' Theorem and this are 2 different things.

Answer (score 0):

You use Pythagoras to find the length of a vector.
Just because $\vec{AC} = \vec{AB} + \vec{BC}$ that doesn't mean $\Vert AC \Vert$ is equal to $\Vert AB \Vert + \Vert BC \Vert$, it's generally less than or equal (triangular inequality).